# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str - for timetables

Tags: class, typeerror

```
dailyTimetable = [
        [{'Physics': '0830'}, {'Computer Science': '0915'}, {'Biology': '1000'}, {'English': '1125'}, {'History':'1210'}, {'DT':'1440'}, {'Maths': '1515'}],
        [{'French':'0830'}, {'English':'0915'}, {'DT':'1000'}, {'Chemistry':'1125'}, {'Computer Science':'1210'}],
        [{'Maths':'0830'}, {'DT':'0915'}, {'Physics':'1000'}, {'Biology':'1125'}, {'Biolody':'1210'}, {'English':'1440'}, {'History':'1515'}],
        [{'Biology':'0830'}, {'French':'0915'}, {'Maths':'1000'}, {'Computer Science':'1125'}, {'Physics':'1210'}],
        ['English', 'French', 'History', 'Computer Science', 'DT', 'Chemistry', 'Chemistry'],
        ['History', 'English', 'Physics', 'Maths','French']
            ]


class timetable:
    def __init__(self, timetable):
        self.timetable = timetable

    def getSubject(self, day, period):
        return list(self.timetable[day-1][period-1])[0]

    def getPeriod(self, day, subject):
        return list(self.timetable[day-1][subject])[1]


test = timetable(dailyTimetable)

print(test.getPeriod(1, 'Physics'))
```

I am trying to make something that gets the 'period' of a timetable but I've got no clue how to do it, this is an attempt and it isn't working, can someone help me!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because you are attempting to access the key 'Physics' from the array of dictionaries. Since you have a array of dictionaries for each day, you need to search the array of periods on that particular day for the matching period, and return that once it has been found. Something like:

```
def getPeriod(self, day, subject):
    todaysTimetable = dailyTimetable[day]
    for currentPeriod in todaysTimetable:
        if subject in currentPeriod:
            return currentPeriod[subject]
```